# How to select first n number of columns from a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I have a DataTable containing dynamic number of rows and dynamic number of columns,

```
col1        col2        col3        col4............colN
________________________________________________________________________
row1col1    row1col2    row1col3    row1col4........row1colN
.           .               .       .               .
.           .               .       .               .
.           .               .       .               .
.           .               .       .               .
.           .               .       .               .
.           .               .       .               .
rowNcol1    rowNcol2    rowNcol3    rowNcol4.......rowNcolN
```

How to select data from first n number of columns from a DataTable?

Comment: Do you want to total column count in first row ?

Comment: no,I want to select data from first 5 columns from the datatable

Comment: What do you mean by `select` datatable.Columns property doesn't help? Do you want to select the data or do you want to display `n` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the columns:

```
   var tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
var cols = tbl.Columns.Cast<System.Data.DataColumn>().Take(20);
```

// if you wish to get first 20 columns...

if you want to get the data, then you have to loop through the columns to get the data.

> var data = cols.SelectMany(x => tbl.Rows.Cast().Take(100).Select(y => y[x]));

of course, this will dump all the data into an ienumerable, if you want to use strong typed object or a list of one dimensional array, believe it's fairly simple, for example:

> var data2 = cols.Select(x =>
>   tbl.Rows.Cast().Take(100).Select(y => y[x]).ToArray());

If you wish to keep the current table and reserve number of columns/rows, you can remove the rest columns/rows:

> ```
>         var tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
>         int totalColumnsToReserve = 20;
>         for (int i = tbl.Columns.Count - 1; i >= totalColumnsToReserve; i--)
>         {
>             tbl.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
>         }
>
>         int totalRowsToReserve = 100;
>         for (int i = tbl.Rows.Count - 1; i >= totalRowsToReserve; i--)
>         {
>             tbl.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
>         }
> ```

Comment: This query is giving columns as rows and again in the row there is enumerable containing column values. is it possible to get it in datatable?

Answer (score 1):

you can use following function to get first n number of columns from DataTable;
where `objSource` is source DataTable and `outputCols` is first n columns required.
If `outputCols` is <= 0 or >= total columns  in source DataTable, then it just returns all columns.

```
private DataTable GetNColumnsFromDataTable(DataTable objSource, int outputCols)
{
    DataTable objOutput = objSource.Copy();

    if (outputCols > 0 && outputCols < objSource.Columns.Count)
    {
        while (outputCols < objOutput.Columns.Count)
        {
            objOutput.Columns.RemoveAt(objOutput.Columns.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    return objOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the rows and for each row iterate through n number of columns. However, I'm not sure how you want to deal with the results.

Example where n is first number of columns:

```
    var data = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
    const int n = 5;
    foreach (var row in data)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        var value = row[i];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get an array of the DataRows using select() then access each row like an array

```
DataTable DT = new DT();
DataRow[] rows = DT.Select();

foreach(DataRow row in rows)
{
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++
    {
          rows[i]; //do whatever you want with this
    }
}
```